# SQL apply status to each row of account if condition is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, window-functions

I have the following dataset,

[image]

and would like to create a "flag" of sorts where any account with a bucket_type = 'Self-pay' and bucket_status = 'Outstanding' receives the description "Self-pay Outstanding" for all rows pertaining to that account. Other instances can be regarded as "N/A". Like so:

[image]

I'm somewhat familiar with row_count(), partition by, and case statements, but I'm not sure how I can combine them together to achieve what I want. I have the following code, and I'm getting tripped up on my case statement.

```
select 
account
,bucket_type
,bucket_status
,case when bucket_type = 'Self-pay' and bucket_status = 'Outstanding' over (partition by account)
then 'Self-pay Outstanding' else null end 
from account_table
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional window `max()`:

```
select t.*,
    case max(case when bucket_type = 'Self-pay' and bucket_status = 'Outstanding' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by account) 
        when 1 then 'Self-pay Outstanding'
        else 'NA'
    end as flag
from mytable t
```

An alternative is an `exists` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    case when exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.account = t.account and t1.bucket_type = 'Self-pay' and t1.bucket_status = 'Outstanding')
        then 'Self-pay Outstanding'
        else 'NA'
    end as flag
from mytable t
```

I can't really tell which solution would perform better. The window function is neater; the subquery would take advantage of an index on `(account, bucket_type, bucket_status)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/306d46/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Account_Table
(
  Account VarChar(50),
  Bucket_Type VarChar(50),
  Bucket_Status VARCHAR(50)
 );
 
 INSERT INTO Account_Table
 VALUES
  ('A', 'Self-pay', 'Outstanding'),
  ('A', 'Prebilled', 'Closed'),
  ('A', 'Primary', 'Closed'),
  ('B', 'Self-pay', 'Closed'),
  ('B', 'Prebilled', 'Closed'),
  ('B', 'Primary', 'Outstanding'),
  ('C', 'Primary', 'Closed'),
  ('C', 'Secondary', 'Outstanding')
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT DISTINCT Account, 'Self-pay Outstanding' as Flag
  FROM Account_Table
  WHERE 
    Bucket_Type = 'Self-Pay' AND
    Bucket_Status = 'Outstanding'
 )
 SELECT A.Account, A.Bucket_Type, A.Bucket_Status, COALESCE(CTE.Flag, 'N/A') AS Flag
 FROM Account_Table A
 LEFT JOIN CTE
   ON CTE.Account = A.Account
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/306d46/4/0)**:

```
| Account | Bucket_Type | Bucket_Status |                 Flag |
|---------|-------------|---------------|----------------------|
|       A |    Self-pay |   Outstanding | Self-pay Outstanding |
|       A |   Prebilled |        Closed | Self-pay Outstanding |
|       A |     Primary |        Closed | Self-pay Outstanding |
|       B |    Self-pay |        Closed |                  N/A |
|       B |   Prebilled |        Closed |                  N/A |
|       B |     Primary |   Outstanding |                  N/A |
|       C |     Primary |        Closed |                  N/A |
|       C |   Secondary |   Outstanding |                  N/A |
```